# subtract values selecting by timestamp self join

Tags: oracle, date, time

I have the following problem:
Table1:

```
id,     timestamp,    value1,value2,value3 
1, 12.01.2017 09:00:01, 234,   345,  456  
2, 12.01.2017 09:00:05, 567,   678,  789  
3, 12.01.2017 09:00:25, 777,   888,  999
```

the values are absolut values. now i need to insert this data into a new table, but as incremental values.
that means i have to find the previous record for each record and subtract the values.
but unfortunately im not getting there...
I tried a self join like this:

```
select  
    se1.timestamp,
    se1.value1,
    se1.value2,
    se1.value3
from
    table1 se1,
    table1 se2
where
    se1.id = se2.id
    and se1.timestamp < (select max(timestamp) from table1)
order by
    timestamp desc
fetch first 100 rows only;
```

it would be great if anyone could help me with this...

The output should look something like this:

```
timestamp,         value1, value2, value3  
12.01.2017 09:00:05, 333,   333,   333  (record from 09:00:01 subtracted)  
12.01.2017 09:00:25, 210,   210,   210  (record from 09:00:05 subtracted)
```

I hope anyone can understand this ;)

Comment: OOps. i forgot to format the code:

Comment: I don't get your question, can you please provide example of desired output?

Comment: You can easily edit your question to format code and data ( hint: ctrl+k)

Comment: @Wernfied Domscheid: I tried to explain it a little bit better in the post. I hope this helps to understand

Comment: @Aleksej: thank you. I updated it now...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you need to compute for every value (`value1`, `value2` and `value3`) the difference between the value in the current row and the value in the preceding row, ordered by `timestamp`.
If so, you may need:

```
with test(id,     timestamp,    value1, value2, value3) as (  
  select 1, to_timestamp('12.01.2017 09:00:01', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 234,   345,  456 from dual union all  
  select 2, to_timestamp('12.01.2017 09:00:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 567,   678,  789 from dual union all  
  select 3, to_timestamp('12.01.2017 09:00:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 777,   888,  999 from dual
)
select timestamp,
       value1 - lag(value1, 1, 0) over ( order by timestamp) increment1,
       value2 - lag(value2, 1, 0) over ( order by timestamp) increment2,
       value3 - lag(value3, 1, 0) over ( order by timestamp) increment3
from test
```

This uses [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/LAG.htm#SQLRF00652) to evaluate the preceding row and make the difference with the value in the current row, thus giving:

```
TIMESTAMP                      INCREMENT1  INCREMENT2  INCREMENT3
12/01/2017 09:00:01,000000000  234         345         456
12/01/2017 09:00:05,000000000  333         333         333
12/01/2017 09:00:25,000000000  210         210         210
```

Notice that `timestamp` is an Oracle type, so it would be better not to use it as the name of a column.

Also, notice the comments by Boneist: in the first version of my answer I used something like `NVL(LAG(..), 0)` to handle the case where `LAG(..)` is `null` (the first row). Boneist's comment made me notice that `LAG` already handles a default value in case the needed preceding row does not exist, thus allowing me to avoid the `NVL`.

Comment: You don't need the NVL here; you can use the additional parameters of [`LAG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) to handle nulls, e.g. `LAG(value1, 1, 0) OVER ...`

Comment: @aleksej Thank you so much. This will help me out... I missed the LAG() function until now... ;) Thanks again!!

Comment: @Monument - you're welcome. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find  something more on how to handle answers to your questions